# drupal 7 lack of understandig location of bartik's color.css

Tags: theming, files

I liked to change some css color styles. I created my own css file and let bartik theme (my enabled theme) know this in its info file. But no changes took effect.
Then i realized, that there are two color.css files. One is in bartik/css/ and the other in sites/default/files/color/. The second one is used. Can someone explain to me, why not all css are just taken from bartik/css. I think i didn't get the concept yet.

Comment: Check this out: http://adaptivethemes.com/how-to-add-css-files-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 1):

The Bartik theme has support for the [Color module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!color!color.module/7), which is a module that allows themes to change the color used in their images, or in their CSS style files basing on a schema defined in the theme settings page.

[image: screenshot]

When the selected color set is not the default one, [color_scheme_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!color!color.module/function/color_scheme_form_submit/7) generates the files that will be used for the theme. The files you have seen inside the sites/default/files/color directory are the ones generated from the Color module, and that will be used for the theme. The files in the theme directory are the ones used when the color set is the default one.

As side note, if you are editing the files used by a theme that supports the Color module, you need to disable, and then re-enable it, or the files used for the theme could still be the old ones.

Comment: I tried to implement these color scheme options for my theme. I have followed all the steps and files  have been generated inside the sites/default/files/color directory from the Color module. 

But those generated css files are not getting substituted in the style tags. Can i know what i did wrong ?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

This second css file may be cache file. Try flushing your cache and then checking if your changes take effect.

Comment: It is not cache. It's the file used from the Color module. Bartik uses it to rewrite its own CSS files.